# como posso retirar todos os espaços de uma string em lua?

Tags: string, lua

eu quero pegar uma string e retirar os espaços em branco contidos nela.`nome = algumacoisa` imagine que isso é uma string, eu quero retirar os espaços em branco entre o "nome" e o "=" e o "=" e o "algumacoisa"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gsub`. Assim `s=s:gsub("%s+","")`.

O padrão `%s+` significa "um ou mais caracteres de espaço (*whitespace*)".